# How to split existing tabularx table over pages

Tags: longtable, tabularx

I'm trying to fit a landscape tabularx table over multiple pages, however with the solutions I've found, I'm not able to do so.
I've also picked up the solution for generating the table itself from another question which really fits my needs as long as I don't have too many rows. So therefore, I'd like to keep that solution (if possible) and just have it modified so that it can fit more rows and break it over several pages, if necessary.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibtotoc,headsepline,smallheadings,oneside,appendixprefix,BCOR5mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eurosym} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{exscale} 
\usepackage{amstext} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[ruled, english]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\newcommand*\OK{\ding{51}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{scrpage2} 
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage[hang,flushmargin,perpage]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}


\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1} 
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75} 
\onehalfspacing 
\definecolor{grey}{gray}{0.5}

\newcommand{\argmax}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmax}}
\newcommand{\argmin}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmin}}

\newenvironment{conditions}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{alph}
\mainmatter

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htp]
\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
\textbf{Avg. F1 Training} & \textbf{Avg. F1 Validation} & \textbf{Avg. Recall Training} & \textbf{Avg. Recall Validation} & \textbf{Avg. Precision Training} & \textbf{Avg. Precision Validation} & \textbf{Gap between F1 Training \& Validation}  \\
\hline
0.97&   0.91&   0.95&   0.88&   0.99&   0.95&   0.06\\
\hline
0.99&   0.94&   0.98&   0.91&   1.00&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.90&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.97&   0.92&   0.95&   0.89&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.92&   0.87&   0.88&   0.82&   0.97&   0.94&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.97&   0.92&   0.95&   0.89&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
0.97&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
0.97&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
0.97&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
0.92&   0.88&   0.89&   0.83&   0.96&   0.93&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.90&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
0.96&   0.92&   0.94&   0.89&   0.98&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
0.97&   0.92&   0.95&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.90&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.90&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.90&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
0.96&   0.92&   0.94&   0.90&   0.98&   0.94&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
0.96&   0.93&   0.94&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
0.77&   0.73&   0.67&   0.63&   0.91&   0.88&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
0.96&   0.92&   0.93&   0.89&   0.98&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
0.95&   0.92&   0.93&   0.89&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.96&   0.93&   0.94&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.95&   0.92&   0.93&   0.89&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.95&   0.92&   0.92&   0.88&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.96&   0.92&   0.93&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.96&   0.92&   0.93&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.90&   0.87&   0.87&   0.83&   0.94&   0.92&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.96&   0.93&   0.93&   0.90&   0.98&   0.96&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.93&   0.90&   0.90&   0.86&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.94&   0.91&   0.91&   0.88&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.95&   0.93&   0.93&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.95&   0.92&   0.92&   0.89&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.95&   0.92&   0.93&   0.90&   0.97&   0.94&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.93&   0.90&   0.89&   0.86&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.95&   0.92&   0.92&   0.90&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.95&   0.92&   0.92&   0.89&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.92&   0.89&   0.88&   0.85&   0.95&   0.93&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.94&   0.92&   0.92&   0.89&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
0.87&   0.84&   0.81&   0.78&   0.94&   0.92&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
0.95&   0.92&   0.92&   0.90&   0.97&   0.95&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
0.93&   0.90&   0.90&   0.87&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
0.93&   0.91&   0.91&   0.88&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
0.94&   0.91&   0.91&   0.89&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
0.92&   0.90&   0.89&   0.87&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
0.93&   0.91&   0.91&   0.89&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
0.88&   0.87&   0.85&   0.82&   0.93&   0.91&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
0.93&   0.91&   0.90&   0.88&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
0.93&   0.91&   0.90&   0.88&   0.96&   0.95&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
0.89&   0.87&   0.84&   0.82&   0.94&   0.93&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
0.72&   0.70&   0.61&   0.59&   0.88&   0.86&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
0.89&   0.87&   0.84&   0.82&   0.94&   0.93&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
0.88&   0.86&   0.82&   0.81&   0.94&   0.93&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
0.91&   0.90&   0.88&   0.86&   0.95&   0.93&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
0.88&   0.87&   0.84&   0.82&   0.94&   0.93&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
0.85&   0.84&   0.80&   0.78&   0.92&   0.91&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
0.88&   0.87&   0.84&   0.83&   0.93&   0.92&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
0.88&   0.87&   0.84&   0.83&   0.93&   0.92&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
0.88&   0.86&   0.83&   0.82&   0.93&   0.92&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
0.87&   0.86&   0.83&   0.81&   0.93&   0.92&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
0.84&   0.83&   0.78&   0.77&   0.91&   0.90&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
0.75&   0.74&   0.70&   0.69&   0.82&   0.81&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
0.74&   0.74&   0.67&   0.67&   0.84&   0.83&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
0.79&   0.78&   0.72&   0.71&   0.87&   0.86&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
0.78&   0.78&   0.71&   0.70&   0.88&   0.88&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
0.75&   0.75&   0.66&   0.66&   0.88&   0.88&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.74&   0.73&   0.65&   0.65&   0.85&   0.85&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.62&   0.62&   0.54&   0.54&   0.73&   0.73&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.74&   0.74&   0.65&   0.65&   0.86&   0.86&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.70&   0.70&   0.61&   0.61&   0.82&   0.82&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.63&   0.63&   0.54&   0.54&   0.76&   0.76&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.63&   0.63&   0.55&   0.55&   0.73&   0.73&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.62&   0.62&   0.55&   0.55&   0.70&   0.70&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.68&   0.68&   0.60&   0.60&   0.77&   0.77&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.65&   0.65&   0.55&   0.55&   0.79&   0.79&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.64&   0.64&   0.54&   0.54&   0.78&   0.78&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.69&   0.69&   0.60&   0.60&   0.82&   0.82&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                      \hline                                      
0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
\end{tabularx}
\caption{caption.}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Which results in this:
[image]

I tried to use the longtable command before the tabularx environment or using the ltablex package but nothing seems to work. Any advice is very welcome!

Comment: Please make your MWE more minimal. There are a lot of packages that are not needed for this specific issue. Please also make sure that you don't load packages more than once. Also, you might want to keep in mind that `hyperref` should (with a few exceptions) be the last package in your preamble. You also used deprecated class options. You might want to replace them with the newer ones.

Comment: Initially, I thought about removing packages but to be honest, I don't know the use for every package as the MWE comes from a template that I use to write my thesis. So eventually, the preamble has grown over the last month and I don't know if any packages may be conflicting each other, despite of being compilable. So I thought it might be useful information.

Comment: Having a compilable MWE that contains too many package is definitely preferrable than having an incomplete example where essential package are missing, so no worries. Regarding "I don't know the use for every package" and "comes from a template" : please do yourself a favor and do some research about the purpose of each package (the short summary at CTAN about each package might be a good point to start from). As your preamble grows over time, you might want to go through it from time to time and reconsider if you really need every package and delete duplicates and unneeded packages.

Comment: For others with similar issues seeing this question: Try `\usepackage{ltablex}` if you haven't already, solved it for my table (but not for OP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest the following layout based on `longtable` and `booktabs`. With some abbreviations in the column headers there is no need to use `\footnotesize`d text or to turn the table to landscape. I have also removed all vertical lines and replaced the horizontal lines by lines and some vertical white spaces from the `booktabs` package that you already load. I have also made use of the `\endhead` and `\endfirsthead` commands from the `longtable` package in order to repeat column headers on all pages.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headsepline,oneside,appendixprefix]{scrbook}

\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

    \pagestyle{empty}
    \pagenumbering{alph}
    \mainmatter
            \begin{longtable}{cccccccc}
            \caption{caption.}\\ 
                \toprule
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{Avg. F1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Avg. Recall} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Avg. Precision} & Gap between F1 \\ \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
                Train. & Valid. & Train. & Valid. & Train. & Valid. & Train. \& Valid.  \\
                \midrule
                \endfirsthead
                \caption{caption. - continued from previous page}\\ 
                \toprule
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{Avg. F1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Avg. Recall} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Avg. Precision} & Gap between F1 \\ \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
                Train. & Valid. & Train. & Valid. & Train. & Valid. & Train. \& Valid.  \\
                \midrule
                \endhead
                0.97&   0.91&   0.95&   0.88&   0.99&   0.95&   0.06\\                      
                0.99&   0.94&   0.98&   0.91&   1.00&   0.96&   0.05\\                                             
                0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.90&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                                             
                0.97&   0.92&   0.95&   0.89&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                                             
                0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.92&   0.87&   0.88&   0.82&   0.97&   0.94&   0.05\\                                                                
                0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                                                                
                0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                                                                
                0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                                                                
                0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                                                                
                0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                                                                
                0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                                                                
                0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                                                                
                0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                                            
                0.97&   0.92&   0.95&   0.89&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                                            
                0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                                            
                0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                                            
                0.97&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.97&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                                                                
                0.97&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.04\\                                                                
                0.92&   0.88&   0.89&   0.83&   0.96&   0.93&   0.04\\                                                                
                0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.90&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                                                                
                0.96&   0.92&   0.94&   0.89&   0.98&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.97&   0.92&   0.95&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.04\\                                             
                0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.90&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                                             
                0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.90&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                                             
                0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.90&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                                             
                0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.04\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.96&   0.92&   0.94&   0.90&   0.98&   0.94&   0.04\\                                             
                0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.04\\                                             
                0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.04\\                                             
                0.96&   0.93&   0.94&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.04\\                                             
                0.77&   0.73&   0.67&   0.63&   0.91&   0.88&   0.04\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.96&   0.92&   0.93&   0.89&   0.98&   0.95&   0.04\\                                                                
                0.95&   0.92&   0.93&   0.89&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                                                                
                0.96&   0.93&   0.94&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                                                                
                0.95&   0.92&   0.93&   0.89&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                                                                
                0.95&   0.92&   0.92&   0.88&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.96&   0.92&   0.93&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                                             
                0.96&   0.92&   0.93&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                                             
                0.90&   0.87&   0.87&   0.83&   0.94&   0.92&   0.03\\                                             
                0.96&   0.93&   0.93&   0.90&   0.98&   0.96&   0.03\\                                             
                0.93&   0.90&   0.90&   0.86&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.94&   0.91&   0.91&   0.88&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                                                                
                0.95&   0.93&   0.93&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                                                                
                0.95&   0.92&   0.92&   0.89&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                                                                
                0.95&   0.92&   0.93&   0.90&   0.97&   0.94&   0.03\\                                                                
                0.93&   0.90&   0.89&   0.86&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.95&   0.92&   0.92&   0.90&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                                                                
                0.95&   0.92&   0.92&   0.89&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                                                                
                0.92&   0.89&   0.88&   0.85&   0.95&   0.93&   0.03\\                                                                
                0.94&   0.92&   0.92&   0.89&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                                                                
                0.87&   0.84&   0.81&   0.78&   0.94&   0.92&   0.02\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.95&   0.92&   0.92&   0.90&   0.97&   0.95&   0.02\\                                             
                0.93&   0.90&   0.90&   0.87&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                                             
                0.93&   0.91&   0.91&   0.88&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                                             
                0.94&   0.91&   0.91&   0.89&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                                             
                0.92&   0.90&   0.89&   0.87&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.93&   0.91&   0.91&   0.89&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                                                                
                0.88&   0.87&   0.85&   0.82&   0.93&   0.91&   0.02\\                                                                
                0.93&   0.91&   0.90&   0.88&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                                                                
                0.93&   0.91&   0.90&   0.88&   0.96&   0.95&   0.02\\                                                                
                0.89&   0.87&   0.84&   0.82&   0.94&   0.93&   0.02\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.72&   0.70&   0.61&   0.59&   0.88&   0.86&   0.02\\                                              
                0.89&   0.87&   0.84&   0.82&   0.94&   0.93&   0.02\\                                              
                0.88&   0.86&   0.82&   0.81&   0.94&   0.93&   0.01\\                                              
                0.91&   0.90&   0.88&   0.86&   0.95&   0.93&   0.01\\                                              
                0.88&   0.87&   0.84&   0.82&   0.94&   0.93&   0.01\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.85&   0.84&   0.80&   0.78&   0.92&   0.91&   0.01\\                                                                
                0.88&   0.87&   0.84&   0.83&   0.93&   0.92&   0.01\\                                                                
                0.88&   0.87&   0.84&   0.83&   0.93&   0.92&   0.01\\                                                                
                0.88&   0.86&   0.83&   0.82&   0.93&   0.92&   0.01\\                                                                
                0.87&   0.86&   0.83&   0.81&   0.93&   0.92&   0.01\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.84&   0.83&   0.78&   0.77&   0.91&   0.90&   0.01\\                                              
                0.75&   0.74&   0.70&   0.69&   0.82&   0.81&   0.01\\                                              
                0.74&   0.74&   0.67&   0.67&   0.84&   0.83&   0.01\\                                              
                0.79&   0.78&   0.72&   0.71&   0.87&   0.86&   0.01\\                                              
                0.78&   0.78&   0.71&   0.70&   0.88&   0.88&   0.01\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.75&   0.75&   0.66&   0.66&   0.88&   0.88&   0.00\\                                              
                0.74&   0.73&   0.65&   0.65&   0.85&   0.85&   0.00\\                                              
                0.62&   0.62&   0.54&   0.54&   0.73&   0.73&   0.00\\                                              
                0.74&   0.74&   0.65&   0.65&   0.86&   0.86&   0.00\\                                              
                0.70&   0.70&   0.61&   0.61&   0.82&   0.82&   0.00\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.63&   0.63&   0.54&   0.54&   0.76&   0.76&   0.00\\                                            
                0.63&   0.63&   0.55&   0.55&   0.73&   0.73&   0.00\\                                            
                0.62&   0.62&   0.55&   0.55&   0.70&   0.70&   0.00\\                                            
                0.68&   0.68&   0.60&   0.60&   0.77&   0.77&   0.00\\                                            
                0.65&   0.65&   0.55&   0.55&   0.79&   0.79&   0.00\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.64&   0.64&   0.54&   0.54&   0.78&   0.78&   0.00\\                                              
                0.69&   0.69&   0.60&   0.60&   0.82&   0.82&   0.00\\                                              
                0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                                              
                0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                                              
                0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                      \addlinespace                                          
                0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                                           
                0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                                           
                0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                                           
                0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                                       
                0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                                              
            \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I think this one is visually more appealing. I opted to go with this one. Works really well!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with longtable.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibtotoc,headsepline,smallheadings,oneside,appendixprefix,BCOR5mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eurosym} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{exscale} 
\usepackage{amstext} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[ruled, english]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\newcommand*\OK{\ding{51}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{scrpage2} 
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage[hang,flushmargin,perpage]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}


\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1} 
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75} 
\onehalfspacing 
\definecolor{grey}{gray}{0.5}

\newcommand{\argmax}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmax}}
\newcommand{\argmin}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmin}}

\newenvironment{conditions}
{\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
    {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}

\begin{document}

    \pagestyle{empty}
    \pagenumbering{alph}
    \mainmatter

    \begin{landscape}

            \footnotesize
            \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                \thead{Avg. F1\\Training} & \thead{Avg. F1\\Validation} & \thead{Avg. Recall\\Training} & \thead{Avg. Recall\\ Validation} & \thead{Avg. Precision\\Training} & \thead{Avg. Precision\\Validation} & \thead{Gap between F1\\ Training \& Validation}  \\
                \hline
                0.97&   0.91&   0.95&   0.88&   0.99&   0.95&   0.06\\
                \hline
                0.99&   0.94&   0.98&   0.91&   1.00&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.90&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.97&   0.92&   0.95&   0.89&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.92&   0.87&   0.88&   0.82&   0.97&   0.94&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.98&   0.93&   0.97&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.97&   0.92&   0.95&   0.89&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.98&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.05\\                      \hline                                          
                0.97&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
                0.97&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
                0.97&   0.93&   0.96&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
                0.92&   0.88&   0.89&   0.83&   0.96&   0.93&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
                0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.90&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
                0.96&   0.92&   0.94&   0.89&   0.98&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
                0.97&   0.92&   0.95&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
                0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.90&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
                0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.90&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
                0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.90&   0.99&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
                0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
                0.96&   0.92&   0.94&   0.90&   0.98&   0.94&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
                0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.91&   0.99&   0.96&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
                0.97&   0.93&   0.95&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
                0.96&   0.93&   0.94&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
                0.77&   0.73&   0.67&   0.63&   0.91&   0.88&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
                0.96&   0.92&   0.93&   0.89&   0.98&   0.95&   0.04\\                      \hline                                          
                0.95&   0.92&   0.93&   0.89&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.96&   0.93&   0.94&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.95&   0.92&   0.93&   0.89&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.95&   0.92&   0.92&   0.88&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.96&   0.92&   0.93&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.96&   0.92&   0.93&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.90&   0.87&   0.87&   0.83&   0.94&   0.92&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.96&   0.93&   0.93&   0.90&   0.98&   0.96&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.93&   0.90&   0.90&   0.86&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.94&   0.91&   0.91&   0.88&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.95&   0.93&   0.93&   0.90&   0.98&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.95&   0.92&   0.92&   0.89&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.95&   0.92&   0.93&   0.90&   0.97&   0.94&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.93&   0.90&   0.89&   0.86&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.95&   0.92&   0.92&   0.90&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.95&   0.92&   0.92&   0.89&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.92&   0.89&   0.88&   0.85&   0.95&   0.93&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.94&   0.92&   0.92&   0.89&   0.97&   0.95&   0.03\\                      \hline                                          
                0.87&   0.84&   0.81&   0.78&   0.94&   0.92&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
                0.95&   0.92&   0.92&   0.90&   0.97&   0.95&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
                0.93&   0.90&   0.90&   0.87&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
                0.93&   0.91&   0.91&   0.88&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
                0.94&   0.91&   0.91&   0.89&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
                0.92&   0.90&   0.89&   0.87&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
                0.93&   0.91&   0.91&   0.89&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
                0.88&   0.87&   0.85&   0.82&   0.93&   0.91&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
                0.93&   0.91&   0.90&   0.88&   0.96&   0.94&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
                0.93&   0.91&   0.90&   0.88&   0.96&   0.95&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
                0.89&   0.87&   0.84&   0.82&   0.94&   0.93&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
                0.72&   0.70&   0.61&   0.59&   0.88&   0.86&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
                0.89&   0.87&   0.84&   0.82&   0.94&   0.93&   0.02\\                      \hline                                          
                0.88&   0.86&   0.82&   0.81&   0.94&   0.93&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
                0.91&   0.90&   0.88&   0.86&   0.95&   0.93&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
                0.88&   0.87&   0.84&   0.82&   0.94&   0.93&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
                0.85&   0.84&   0.80&   0.78&   0.92&   0.91&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
                0.88&   0.87&   0.84&   0.83&   0.93&   0.92&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
                0.88&   0.87&   0.84&   0.83&   0.93&   0.92&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
                0.88&   0.86&   0.83&   0.82&   0.93&   0.92&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
                0.87&   0.86&   0.83&   0.81&   0.93&   0.92&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
                0.84&   0.83&   0.78&   0.77&   0.91&   0.90&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
                0.75&   0.74&   0.70&   0.69&   0.82&   0.81&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
                0.74&   0.74&   0.67&   0.67&   0.84&   0.83&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
                0.79&   0.78&   0.72&   0.71&   0.87&   0.86&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
                0.78&   0.78&   0.71&   0.70&   0.88&   0.88&   0.01\\                      \hline                                          
                0.75&   0.75&   0.66&   0.66&   0.88&   0.88&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.74&   0.73&   0.65&   0.65&   0.85&   0.85&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.62&   0.62&   0.54&   0.54&   0.73&   0.73&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.74&   0.74&   0.65&   0.65&   0.86&   0.86&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.70&   0.70&   0.61&   0.61&   0.82&   0.82&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.63&   0.63&   0.54&   0.54&   0.76&   0.76&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.63&   0.63&   0.55&   0.55&   0.73&   0.73&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.62&   0.62&   0.55&   0.55&   0.70&   0.70&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.68&   0.68&   0.60&   0.60&   0.77&   0.77&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.65&   0.65&   0.55&   0.55&   0.79&   0.79&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.64&   0.64&   0.54&   0.54&   0.78&   0.78&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.69&   0.69&   0.60&   0.60&   0.82&   0.82&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                      \hline                                          
                0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                      \hline                                      
                0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00&   0.00\\                      \hline      \caption{caption.}                                        
            \end{longtable}


    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

This works. To get the headers smaller i used \thead.
[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Do you know if it's possible to make your solution a bit more 'compact'? If I use my solution with less rows it looks like the one above (compared to your solution below):

 https://i.imgur.com/O6Lujoo.png

Comment: I think the main difference is the breakage of the titles in the first row. You can set them in my solution with \\ in the place you want it to break. (Especially in the last column)

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot that a long table is *not* a float, so you shouldn't use the `table` environment, and you should the syntax of longtable (`endfirsthead` and the like). I removed from your preamble the unnecessary loading of `amsmath`(you load  `mathtools`),  `amsfont` (loaded by `amssymb`) and `color`(loading `xcolor`). As the table, as is, could not fit the margins, I used  `\thead` for the column heads.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibtotoc,headsepline,smallheadings,oneside,appendixprefix,BCOR5mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}%
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[ruled, english]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\newcommand*\OK{\ding{51}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}

\usepackage[hang,flushmargin,perpage]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}


\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}
\onehalfspacing
\definecolor{grey}{gray}{0.5}

\newcommand{\argmax}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmax}}
\newcommand{\argmin}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmin}}

\newenvironment{conditions}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{alph}
\mainmatter

\begin{landscape}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{|*{8}{C|}}
\caption{caption.}\medskip\\
\hline
\thead{Avg. F1\\ Training} & \thead{Avg. F1\\ Validation} & \thead{Avg. Recall\\ Training} & \thead{Avg. Recall\\ Validation} & \thead{Avg. Precision\\ Training} & \thead{Avg. Precision\\ Validation} & \thead{Gap between \\ F1 Training \\\& Validation} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{caption. (\emph{continued})}\medskip\\
\hline
\thead{Avg. F1\\ Training} & \thead{Avg. F1\\ Validation} & \thead{Avg. Recall \\ Training} & \thead{Avg. Recall\\ Validation} & \thead{Avg. Precision\\ Training} & \thead{Avg. Precision\\ Validation} & \thead{Gap between\\ F1 Training \\ \& Validation} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline\multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{\emph{To be continued}}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
0.97& 0.91& 0.95& 0.88& 0.99& 0.95& 0.06\\
\hline
0.99& 0.94& 0.98& 0.91& 1.00& 0.96& 0.05\\ \hline
0.98& 0.93& 0.97& 0.90& 0.99& 0.95& 0.05\\ \hline
0.97& 0.92& 0.95& 0.89& 0.99& 0.95& 0.05\\ \hline
0.98& 0.93& 0.96& 0.91& 0.99& 0.95& 0.05\\ \hline
0.92& 0.87& 0.88& 0.82& 0.97& 0.94& 0.05\\ \hline
0.98& 0.93& 0.97& 0.91& 0.99& 0.95& 0.05\\ \hline
0.98& 0.93& 0.97& 0.91& 0.99& 0.96& 0.05\\ \hline
0.98& 0.93& 0.97& 0.91& 0.99& 0.96& 0.05\\ \hline
0.98& 0.93& 0.97& 0.91& 0.99& 0.96& 0.05\\ \hline
0.98& 0.93& 0.97& 0.91& 0.99& 0.96& 0.05\\ \hline
0.98& 0.93& 0.97& 0.91& 0.99& 0.96& 0.05\\ \hline
0.98& 0.93& 0.97& 0.91& 0.99& 0.96& 0.05\\ \hline
0.98& 0.93& 0.96& 0.91& 0.99& 0.95& 0.05\\ \hline
0.98& 0.93& 0.96& 0.91& 0.99& 0.95& 0.05\\ \hline
0.98& 0.93& 0.96& 0.91& 0.99& 0.95& 0.05\\ \hline
0.97& 0.92& 0.95& 0.89& 0.99& 0.96& 0.05\\ \hline
0.98& 0.93& 0.96& 0.91& 0.99& 0.95& 0.05\\ \hline
0.98& 0.93& 0.96& 0.91& 0.99& 0.96& 0.05\\ \hline
0.97& 0.93& 0.96& 0.91& 0.99& 0.95& 0.04\\ \hline
0.97& 0.93& 0.96& 0.91& 0.99& 0.95& 0.04\\ \hline
0.97& 0.93& 0.96& 0.91& 0.99& 0.96& 0.04\\ \hline
0.92& 0.88& 0.89& 0.83& 0.96& 0.93& 0.04\\ \hline
0.97& 0.93& 0.95& 0.90& 0.99& 0.95& 0.04\\ \hline
0.96& 0.92& 0.94& 0.89& 0.98& 0.95& 0.04\\ \hline
0.97& 0.92& 0.95& 0.90& 0.98& 0.95& 0.04\\ \hline
0.97& 0.93& 0.95& 0.90& 0.99& 0.95& 0.04\\ \hline
0.97& 0.93& 0.95& 0.90& 0.99& 0.95& 0.04\\ \hline
0.97& 0.93& 0.95& 0.90& 0.99& 0.95& 0.04\\ \hline
0.97& 0.93& 0.95& 0.91& 0.99& 0.96& 0.04\\ \hline
0.96& 0.92& 0.94& 0.90& 0.98& 0.94& 0.04\\ \hline
0.97& 0.93& 0.95& 0.91& 0.99& 0.96& 0.04\\ \hline
0.97& 0.93& 0.95& 0.90& 0.98& 0.95& 0.04\\ \hline
0.96& 0.93& 0.94& 0.90& 0.98& 0.95& 0.04\\ \hline
0.77& 0.73& 0.67& 0.63& 0.91& 0.88& 0.04\\ \hline
0.96& 0.92& 0.93& 0.89& 0.98& 0.95& 0.04\\ \hline
0.95& 0.92& 0.93& 0.89& 0.98& 0.95& 0.03\\ \hline
0.96& 0.93& 0.94& 0.90& 0.98& 0.95& 0.03\\ \hline
0.95& 0.92& 0.93& 0.89& 0.97& 0.95& 0.03\\ \hline
0.95& 0.92& 0.92& 0.88& 0.98& 0.95& 0.03\\ \hline
0.96& 0.92& 0.93& 0.90& 0.98& 0.95& 0.03\\ \hline
0.96& 0.92& 0.93& 0.90& 0.98& 0.95& 0.03\\ \hline
0.90& 0.87& 0.87& 0.83& 0.94& 0.92& 0.03\\ \hline
0.96& 0.93& 0.93& 0.90& 0.98& 0.96& 0.03\\ \hline
0.93& 0.90& 0.90& 0.86& 0.97& 0.95& 0.03\\ \hline
0.94& 0.91& 0.91& 0.88& 0.97& 0.95& 0.03\\ \hline
0.95& 0.93& 0.93& 0.90& 0.98& 0.95& 0.03\\ \hline
0.95& 0.92& 0.92& 0.89& 0.97& 0.95& 0.03\\ \hline
0.95& 0.92& 0.93& 0.90& 0.97& 0.94& 0.03\\ \hline
0.93& 0.90& 0.89& 0.86& 0.97& 0.95& 0.03\\ \hline
0.95& 0.92& 0.92& 0.90& 0.97& 0.95& 0.03\\ \hline
0.95& 0.92& 0.92& 0.89& 0.97& 0.95& 0.03\\ \hline
0.92& 0.89& 0.88& 0.85& 0.95& 0.93& 0.03\\ \hline
0.94& 0.92& 0.92& 0.89& 0.97& 0.95& 0.03\\ \hline
0.87& 0.84& 0.81& 0.78& 0.94& 0.92& 0.02\\ \hline
0.95& 0.92& 0.92& 0.90& 0.97& 0.95& 0.02\\ \hline
0.93& 0.90& 0.90& 0.87& 0.96& 0.94& 0.02\\ \hline
0.93& 0.91& 0.91& 0.88& 0.96& 0.94& 0.02\\ \hline
0.94& 0.91& 0.91& 0.89& 0.96& 0.94& 0.02\\ \hline
0.92& 0.90& 0.89& 0.87& 0.96& 0.94& 0.02\\ \hline
0.93& 0.91& 0.91& 0.89& 0.96& 0.94& 0.02\\ \hline
0.88& 0.87& 0.85& 0.82& 0.93& 0.91& 0.02\\ \hline
0.93& 0.91& 0.90& 0.88& 0.96& 0.94& 0.02\\ \hline
0.93& 0.91& 0.90& 0.88& 0.96& 0.95& 0.02\\ \hline
0.89& 0.87& 0.84& 0.82& 0.94& 0.93& 0.02\\ \hline
0.72& 0.70& 0.61& 0.59& 0.88& 0.86& 0.02\\ \hline
0.89& 0.87& 0.84& 0.82& 0.94& 0.93& 0.02\\ \hline
0.88& 0.86& 0.82& 0.81& 0.94& 0.93& 0.01\\ \hline
0.91& 0.90& 0.88& 0.86& 0.95& 0.93& 0.01\\ \hline
0.88& 0.87& 0.84& 0.82& 0.94& 0.93& 0.01\\ \hline
0.85& 0.84& 0.80& 0.78& 0.92& 0.91& 0.01\\ \hline
0.88& 0.87& 0.84& 0.83& 0.93& 0.92& 0.01\\ \hline
0.88& 0.87& 0.84& 0.83& 0.93& 0.92& 0.01\\ \hline
0.88& 0.86& 0.83& 0.82& 0.93& 0.92& 0.01\\ \hline
0.87& 0.86& 0.83& 0.81& 0.93& 0.92& 0.01\\ \hline
0.84& 0.83& 0.78& 0.77& 0.91& 0.90& 0.01\\ \hline
0.75& 0.74& 0.70& 0.69& 0.82& 0.81& 0.01\\ \hline
0.74& 0.74& 0.67& 0.67& 0.84& 0.83& 0.01\\ \hline
0.79& 0.78& 0.72& 0.71& 0.87& 0.86& 0.01\\ \hline
0.78& 0.78& 0.71& 0.70& 0.88& 0.88& 0.01\\ \hline
0.75& 0.75& 0.66& 0.66& 0.88& 0.88& 0.00\\ \hline
0.74& 0.73& 0.65& 0.65& 0.85& 0.85& 0.00\\ \hline
0.62& 0.62& 0.54& 0.54& 0.73& 0.73& 0.00\\ \hline
0.74& 0.74& 0.65& 0.65& 0.86& 0.86& 0.00\\ \hline
0.70& 0.70& 0.61& 0.61& 0.82& 0.82& 0.00\\ \hline
0.63& 0.63& 0.54& 0.54& 0.76& 0.76& 0.00\\ \hline
0.63& 0.63& 0.55& 0.55& 0.73& 0.73& 0.00\\ \hline
0.62& 0.62& 0.55& 0.55& 0.70& 0.70& 0.00\\ \hline
0.68& 0.68& 0.60& 0.60& 0.77& 0.77& 0.00\\ \hline
0.65& 0.65& 0.55& 0.55& 0.79& 0.79& 0.00\\ \hline
0.64& 0.64& 0.54& 0.54& 0.78& 0.78& 0.00\\ \hline
0.69& 0.69& 0.60& 0.60& 0.82& 0.82& 0.00\\ \hline
0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00\\ \hline
0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00\\ \hline
0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00\\ \hline
0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00\\ \hline
0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00\\ \hline
0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00\\ \hline
0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00\\ \hline
0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]